How to put it in order Excel to JS
guys
I have a program that reads data from Excel and then compares it with the numbers entered by the user.
My data is Height and Width (this is entered by the user)
and using this data I would like the price to be displayed. (which is also included in the excel table).
My question is: how to best arrange the data in excel to implement the comparison code in the next steps.

